# Real time form validation with Springboot, Thymeleaf and webflux

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I want to know if it is possible to generate a form section with a realtime validation using Springboot, Thymeleaf and webflux.
I was looking for some documentation about this topic on webflux page but i dind't find anything about it.
The common way to do it is using thymeleaf with javascript but I don't want to use it
I tried to implement this code but there are not realtime validation on the form:

```
//Webflux
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Controller
public class FormController {

    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "form"; 
    }

    @PostMapping("/validate")
    public Mono<String> validate(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "error.username", "name is required");
        }
        if (user.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.email", "email is required");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return Mono.just("form");
        } else {
            return Mono.just("success"); 
        }
    }
}

//thymleaf, form.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
    <!-- Altri tag head... -->
</head>
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/validate}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" required>
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}" class="error-message"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" required>
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}" class="error-message"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Invia</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```